# I want to know something about webpack(use react)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

there is my code, I use many time to solve this problem, but I can't solve it， I need help
I find many ways to solve it , and I found there are many situtaion may produce this problem.
My webpack version is "^4.44.1", my webpack-cli version is "^3.3.12"

```js
// webpack.common.js

const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const os = require("os");
const HappyPack = require("happypack");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const happyThreadPool = HappyPack.ThreadPool({ size: os.cpus().length });
const srcDir = path.join(__dirname, "../src");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, "../src/index.js"),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../dist"),
    filename: "[name].[chunk:8].js",
    chunkFilename: "chunk/[name].[chunkhash:8].js",
  },
  model: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "less-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: ["url-loader"],
        include: [srcDir],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: ["url-loader"],
        include: [srcDir],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: ["url-loader"],
        include: [srcDir],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: [srcDir],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: ["babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true"],
      },
    ],
  },
  // 插件
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        context: __dirname,
        postcss: [autoprefixer],
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: `${srcDir}/index.html`,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      chunkFilename: "chunk/[id].[contenthash:8].css",
    }),
    //开启 happypack 的线程池
    new HappyPack({
      id: "happybabel",
      loaders: ["babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true"],
      threadPool: happyThreadPool,
      verbose: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": srcDir,
      "@pages": `${srcDir}/pages`,
    },
  },
};
```

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common.js");

// const

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
  mode: "development",
  // 开发环境本地启动的服务配置
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    // historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    // 接口代理转发
    proxy: {
      "/testapi": {
        target: "",
        // changeOrigin: true,
        // secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { "^/testapi": "" },
      },
    },
  },
  // plugins: [
  //   // new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  //   // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  // ],
});
```

//webpack.dev.js
// my document

I found I should use LoaderOptionsPlugin, but I can't add plugin by npm or yarn

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve?